# how to execute system commands using psysh php?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to execute system commands E.g `ls -la`, `whoami` and etc... using psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.10 - cli) by Justin Hileman on linux ?

Currently when I do: `shell_exec('whoami') or exec()` i am getting below error:

> PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined funcion exec() in Psy Shell code on line 1

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the command in backticks.

```
>>> `date`
=> "Tue Jul  9 11:18:27 EDT 2019\n"
```

You can also interpolate variables:

```
>>> $cmd = 'date';
=> "date"
>>> `$cmd`
=> "Tue Jul  9 11:20:07 EDT 2019\n"
```

Source:
https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Shell-integration

Answer (score -1):

if got anything like

> PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant whoami - assumed 'whoami' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in phar://eval()'d code on line 1

then,
`ls`      --> to show variable
`ls`
Variables: `$tokyo`
show `$tokyo`

```
getcwd()

get_current_user()

system('echo test')

scandir("/home")

file_get_contents("/etc/os-release")

echo file_get_contents("/home/nairobi/ca.key")
```